# Show that $\int _0^{\infty }\:\frac{dz}{\sqrt{e^{2z}-1}}=\int _0^{1\:}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}=\frac{\pi }{2}$

Tags: integration, improper-integrals, substitution

The question is as follows:

By appropriate substitutions, show that $\int _0^{\infty }\:\frac{dz}{\sqrt{e^{2z}-1}}=\int _0^{1\:}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}=\frac{\pi }{2}$

Comment: Hint: it's probably best to evaluate the second integral first, with $x=\sin t$. Then you can turn the second integral into the first, with $x=e^{-z}$, i.e. $z=\ln\csc t$.

Comment: (A) Use $y=e^z$ , the limits will change to $1,\infty$ , then use $x=1/y$ , the limits will change to $1,0$ with a negative $dx$ , hence the limits will change to $0,1$. (B) When evaluating that Integral , use trig which @J.G. is suggesting.

Comment: Would it be possible for a step-by-step explanation on converting the second integral into the first? Am struggling even with the substitution given.

Answer (score 4):

Let $x = e^{-z} \iff z=-\ln(x)$.

Then $x\to0 \iff z\to\infty$ and $x\to1 \iff z=0$.

Differentiating, we also have $dx=-e^{-z}\,dz \iff dz=-\frac{dx}x$.

Thus

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{dz}{\sqrt{e^{2z}-1}} = \int_1^0 \frac{-\frac{dx}x}{\sqrt{\frac1{x^2} - 1}} = \int_0^1 \frac{dx}{x\sqrt{\frac1{x^2}-1}} = \int_0^1 \frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$$